# Lowercase i displays as uppercase i

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, browser, internet-explorer, character-encoding

This is driving me crazy now.

Some websites I visit always display the letter i as capital I instead. Even though it is in the middle of a word. See example:

[image]

- This happens both with Chrome and Edge (IE) on Windows 10 machine
- Same happens from a Virtual Machine hosted on Azure.
- Displays correctly on PC with Windows 7 and my android tablet.

I cannot remember other websites that do this but this one is from http://www.entrepreneur.com/

Comment: What if you zoom in (`Ctrl` + `+`)? Does the dot separate from the *i* or do they still stick together?

Comment: Is it only on specific sites? in that case inspect the CSS in your browser's developer tools to determine whether the site is specifying a font, or an odd font-family.

Comment: @Hexaholic Damn ... spot on. Zooming in to 125% and then it displays normally. Strange stuff :D

Comment: @FrankThomas so it is some strange font they use that my browser doesn't render correctly or what... :)

Comment: @Pepys Might be a font that has a small gap in the *i*, combined with a small font size. The resulting space below the dot is probably smaller than a pixel of your screen, so it just can't be displayed. I wonder if someone has a solution for this...

Comment: @Hexaholic yeah good point. It must be just a displaying issue when the font is too small. Mine is default though. 
Only solution I can think of is have all problematic websites set to 110% scaling. Chrome saves that so it will always be the zooming level you set.

Comment: @Hexaholic: Why don't you post an answer?  This seems like something useful to other users.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't consider this a solution, it's just defining the problem.

Comment: @Hexaholic: The "solution" is that it doesn't need a solution because it isn't really a problem.  That knowledge will answer the question for others who experience it.

Comment: @fixer1234 yeAh it is not A reAl problem At All but is simply Annoying reAding 2-pAge Article with rAndom cApitAl letters (sorry :)

Comment: LOL.  Yeah, I could have worded that comment better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's still a lowercase *i*!

What you are experiencing seems to be a combination of a custom font on the website and a small font size. It is simply not large enough for your screen.

As you say, zooming into the text on the page makes the white space between the dot and the rest of the *i* visible. This proves that the problem is the resolution of your screen, which does not provide a pixel size small enough to display the white pixel below the dot.

There are two workarounds (not solutions) I can think of:

- Slightly increasing the zoom level by about 10% is an easy workaround. It's quickly done and browsers keep the setting for all tabs (at least Chrome does).
- If you really need a permanent solution, a user script plugin like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome) might be a way to automatically increase font sizes on small text elements. You will have to know some JavaScript, as a complete tutorial would be out of scope of this post.